# Is AWS EFS fast enough for PHP code execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nfs, amazon-efs

I'm wondering if EFS on AWS is fast enough to store PHP and execute PHP code? Or does the time it takes to access the files on the network when an HTTP request comes in, make this a poor solution?

Comment: I don't have any metrics but my guess is that EFS access will always be faster than Web server PHP render + time to send to web client

Comment: It always dependos on your requirements but the use of EFS must always be justified in order to the shared infrastructure. Many popular PHP CMS woks fine (in my experience) under EFS but of course, EBS is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on your use case. Is it slower than EBS or ephemeral storage? Yes. Is it too slow for your use case? Hard to say.

When using EFS you are bound to the network IO availability on the shared infrastructure that your EC2 VM is running on.

Comment: Network infrastructure capacity in AWS is not oversubscribed. You are not competing with anyone but yourself for network bandwidth.
 A more significant factor is the fact that EFS scales its throughout capacity up with the total storage.  Small EFS filesystems are much slower than large ones, by design.  [Each 1 GiB stored results in replenishing your I/O token bucket at a rate of 50 KiB/s](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/performance.html) and this aspect of the design of the service  seems to be often overlooked.  You can only make it faster by increasing the total data stored.

Comment: Wow, interesting, I definitely didn't know that. You can't just pay more for more fastness?

Comment: You can now! https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-provisioned-throughput-for-amazon-elastic-file-system-efs/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's fast enough, but why bother? EBS is faster and the PHP code itself should not be changing while an individual instance is running in production. Usually you'll spin up an EC2 instance and deploy the code to the EBS storage.

Using EFS to store your application code would be an unnecessary ci/cd shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Samuel. The reason is because I'm working on building a scalable system using Docker. I want the same data to be available in all containers, so I thought EFS was the natural choice.  I'm using swarm mode, so using volumes and EBS seems really hard to setup. There are plugins like rexray, but I'm not sure how ready these are for production. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @NickLang usually as part of a build process you'd package up your code inside a docker image and then can deploy that to any docker container and your code and all dependencies are already contained. In your comment you said "data" but php code is not data. If you want shared data then EFS is an option but there are often better options.. ElasticCache, Database, NoSQL, message queues...

Comment: right, except in this application, the php code is a user-space thing. is it the users that upload arbitrary code, so I can't package their code into an image. i am however packaging phpfpm into an image which is what is executing the code. but the phpfpm image has a bind mounted volume at /mnt which comes from an EFS volume. it seems not so unusual. i know that using EBS would be better, but i'm using swarm mode so this means new replicas would all need the SAME volumes on different nodes. these volumes could be big so I wasn't sure this was viable to be copying them when needed.

Comment: @NickLang interesting, seems very unusual situation so perhaps an alternate solution like EFS is a good choice in your specific use case.